# Is there any way to change boot device?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, usb-installation

I recently made an Ubuntu full installation USB drive while being booted to ram. But when I'm in the boot menu it says that the boot device is the internal ssd that I have in my laptop even though I made sure to select the USB as the boot device in the installation. I even did it twice. So is there an easy way to change the boot device?

Edit 1: the only partition I made was an EXT4 root partition for the Ubuntu 18.04.1 installation. I think I am missing the boot files

Comment: Is the boot options setup in the BIOS?

Comment: I tried making a new boot option from the BIOS but the USB didn't show. I even tried booting from the USB but it says "Not a valid boot option" or something like that. I think that the ssd contains all the boot files for the USB drive

Comment: I should think that the BIOS needs to see it else I doubt although I have no experience with SSD devices. Please supply your system specs.

Comment: I followed a guide which said that it might cause problems if there was internal storage on the device

Comment: Did they not state what should be done in that case?

Comment: Quote: "If there is an internal drive, things may be more tricky in order to avoid writing bootloading things to the internal drive, but this is not due to the fact that it is installed to the same drive as the system was booted from."

Answer (score 0):

See bugs 1173457 and 1366546 for the problem installing in UEFI mode to a second disk. If you put an EFI partition on the USB, just copy everything from the internal disk's EFI to the USB's EFI and it should then be bootable.  The internal disk's EFI needs the USB to run grub because the EFI's stub /ubuntu/grub.cfg has a UUID pointing to the USB's root.  Edit the UUID to be your internal disk's root, and it should work without the USB.

Comment: I only made a root partition in EXT4 to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 since the guys helping me told me only that was necessary

Comment: @cephlot - please add new information to your original question; do not bury it in comments. This is a fully appropriate answer, given the limited original information.

Comment: Of course! I'm sorry

Comment: I'll try your solution when I get back home!